# Javascript only working in Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI to build tabs on my page. That works well until I add this following piece of code.

```
$(function () {
    $('#tabs').children("div").each(function (index) {
        $('#tabs').tabs('load', index);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to preload the tabs. What is interesting, is that if i run this through Firebug and put a breakpoint in that piece of code and step through, the code works perfectly. Otherwise the tabs are rendered, but the content within the tabs is not. This issue has been driving me crazy! Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have loose console.log's?

Comment: Try adding in some console.log messages to do some poor-man's tracing (ie. add a console.log message at each step of the way, see which the last message is to see how far the code runs). If it runs all the way through, console.log some values (eg. `this` inside the each above, log the response of the load call etc). You are probably trying to interact with something that doesn't exist yet (hasn't been returned/rendered).

Comment: FYI, I found this page through a SO recommended answers, but this is a different question. My problem was my js code was only working with Firebug open. Incase anyone files this the same way I found it, it is a console.log issue with Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963354/why-is-firefox-3-breaking-with-console-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the jQuery UI source for tabs the problem shows itself pretty fast, [here's the start of what happens when you call that `load` function](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L589):

```
load: function(index) {
  index = this._getIndex(index);
  var self = this, o = this.options, a = this.anchors.eq(index)[0], 
             url = $.data(a, 'load.tabs');
  this.abort();  //uh oh
```

When you call `load` on a tab, the first thing it does is [kill any *other* tabs running an AJAX call](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L661).  So if you look at your page it is pre-loading the tabs, but only the *last* tab, because in a quick loop, each tab kills the previous one's AJAX request.

I think you'll want to re-visit how you're doing this as a whole, since the AJAX model is intended to load from the anchors (the `<div>` elements shouldn't be there at all) I'm not sure *exactly* how your markup looks here.

You have 2 options though, you can either do the AJAX loads yourself (better IMO), *or* use the built-in but do it sequentially, like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  load: function(event, ui) {
    if(ui.index != $("#tabs a").length - 1) //not on the last tab
      $(this).tabs('load', ui.index + 1);   //load the next tab
  }
}).tabs('load', 0);                         //kick off the first
```

I don't have a good environment to test the above, but we're basically using the [`load` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-load) which fires when one tab *finishes* loading, then we start the next (so we never abort the one before in the loop).  This is much slower, since we're doing serial and not parallel requests...this is why for performance I recommend you make the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) call yourself outside anything [`.tabs()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) offers.

Comment: Excellent help! Thank you, Nick. I think I understand what you are saying about AJAX loading from the anchors, but, being new to AJAX, if you could flesh that out a bit more for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

pretty simple solution - if you have any console.log(s) in your source, in Firefox this will break your application if Firebug is turned off.

You can do 2 things:

1. remove all console.logs(s) from your source by hand
2. better, use a little toConsole wrapper function, so that there is only one location where you have console.log in your code, so you can easily turn it off when you're finished with debugging:

```
toConsole: function( obj ) { console.log( obj ); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem (dynamic content only working when I stepped through it in firebug).

Problem was I was loading xml content but not setting the `async` property.

My code originally looked like:

```
var xmlDoc = createDocument(); &nbsp;//createDocument() was a cross browser solution for creating xml
xmlDoc.load("file.xml");
```

Changing the code to:

```
var xmlDoc = createDocument();
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load("file.xml");
```

did the trick for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this line looks problematic to me:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('load', index);
```

I believe you are going to have more than one tab but you are using id `#tab` which should be used once per element per page. Try using a class for those tabs instead:

```
$('.tabs').tabs('load', index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any console functions being used in the remote content that is loaded? One change that is obvious when Firebug is enabled vs when it is not, is the addition of all these console.* functions to the global object. So if you have for example a log statement:

```
console.log("hello")
alert("world");
```

this will only alert "world" if Firebug is enabled, otherwise a call to `console.log` will throw a `ReferenceError` error and none of the subsequent code will run resulting in no alerts being shown.

One other possibility I can imagine has to do with asynchronous loading of content. When you set breakpoints, it adds time to the remote content that is loading while you are waiting at the breakpoint. By the time you move forward that content is potentially loaded and execution proceeds as normal. However, when there are no breakpoints the script will continue executing without stops and may break. This, of course, is just a theory.

Comment: I don't have any console.log statements in my script (remove them after I found another answer where this caused problems), but I definitely was thinking that your theory is right.  Just wasn't sure how to solve it.